# Merge {conditional} and {ifthen}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The tags [conditional](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional) and [ifthen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ifthen) are used interchangeably. So I think they can be merged (I'd merge into [conditional](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional) and rename that to [conditionals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditionals)).

Comment: One is a package, the other encompasses a much larger set of things. I forget what the standard on packages tags is, but if we have tags for other packages, then it makes sense to have a tag for `ifthen`. Otherwise, this seems like a good merge.

Comment: @TH. If i haven't miscounted, 2 out of the 19 {ifthen} questions are actually about the package. I think people use both tags as concept tags.

Comment: I'm for merging. If necessary, we could create an {ifthen-package} tag.

Comment: @lockstep, @Caramdir: Why not just retag the 17? I'm pretty sure none of the other package tags have a -package suffix (although, it wouldn't be horrible if they did).

Comment: TH.: This would flood the starting page with old questions. (Been there, done that. `;-)`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's meaningful and there are some votes, I

- renamed [conditional](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional) to [conditionals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditionals)
- made [ifthen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ifthen) to a synonym mapping to [conditionals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditionals)
- merged

Perhaps somebody would create or suggest a tag wiki for [conditionals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditionals).

Answer (score 1):

The [ifthen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ifthen) tag was resurrected for a question specifically about the [`ifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) package. At the moment, the tag features four questions.